# How to inherit Common object with other objects in javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am working with javascript. I would like to inherit Common object with other objects in javascript. Is it possible to do it? I mean to convert this js to a prototype model.

```
function setEvent(evt, ele, callback) {
    var ele = getEle(ele);
    if (ele.length === undefined) {
        ele.addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
    } else if (ele.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            ele[i].addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getEle(ele) {
    var _idf = ele.charAt(0);
    if (_idf == "#") {
        var _ele = document.getElementById(ele.substr(1));
        return _ele;
    } else if (_idf == ".") {
        var _els = document.getElementsByClassName(ele.substr(1));
        return _els;
    }
    return ele;
}

function getInnerHtml(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}

function getValue(elem) {

    return elem.value;

}

setEvent("click", ".input", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    var _num = getInnerHtml("math");
    _num = _num + "" + getValue(this);
    document.getElementById("math").innerHTML = _num;

});
```

Comment: What does "inherit Common object" mean?

Comment: All this functions need to written in prototype mode

Comment: function Common() {

}

Common.prototype.setEvent = function() { 




 };

common.prototype.getEle = function(){


};

common.prototype.getInnerHtml = function(){




};

Like                                                                                                           common.prototype.getVal = function(){



};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand what type of object model you're trying to build since you did not describe any requirements or desires in that regard.  Here's one idea that kind of works like jQuery does:

```
function core(selector) {
    if (!(this instanceof core)) {
        return new core(selector);
    }
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (items) {
        this.items = Array.prototype.slice.call(items);
    } else {
        this.items = [];
    }
    this.length = this.items.length;
    return this;
}

core.prototype = {
    each: function(fn) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            fn.call(this.items[i]);
        }
        return this;
    },
    firstProp: function(propName, defaultVal) {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            var val = this.items[0][propName];
            return  val !== undefined ? val : defaultVal;
        } else {
            return defaultVal;
        }

    },
    getHTML: function() {
        return this.firstProp("innerHTML", "");
    },
    setHTML: function(html) {
        return this.each(function() {
            this.innerHTML = html;
        });
    },
    on: function(event, fn) {
        return this.each(function() {
            this.addEventListener(event, fn);
        });
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.firstProp("value", "");
    }
};
```

And, then a usage example like yours:

```
core(".input").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(this.value);
    var math = core("#math");
    math.setHTML(math.getHTML() + this.value);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t56L4p5f/

Comment: I need common object like functin common(){} and then give properties like common.prototype.setEvent=function(){} ,common.prototype.getVal=function(){}, common.prototype.getInnerHtml(){} after that create function calculator and add all these properties (inherit) like Calculator.prototype = new Common;  then how can I give fuctionalities like setEvent("click", ".input", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    var _num = getInnerHtml("math");
    _num = _num + "" + getValue(this);
    document.getElementById("math").innerHTML = _num;

}); to that function

Comment: @appu - I still have NO idea what you're trying to do.  I showed you how to define an object with methods on the prototype.  Perhaps you can take that and turn that concept into whatever it is you want. If you're just asking how to do prototype inheritance in Javascript there are thousands of articles on that available in a Google search.